# Replacing the duplicate function for the 'unique' plugin

Tags: jstree

I am trying to write my own [$.jstree.defaults.unique.duplicate](https://www.jstree.com/api/#/?q=dup&f=$.jstree.defaults.unique.duplicate) function and replace it.

I tried doing so in the following jsFiddle (line: 68):

```js
$.jstree.defaults.unique.duplicate = function(name, counter){
    return name + "_test";
};
```

Steps to test:

1. Select `Devices`
2. Create Node called Node1
3. Create Another node under Devices called Node1
   It will use the jstree default method to replace it with the default node name vs what my function provides

http://jsfiddle.net/2mbq86at/

Am I doing something wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you specify text to use in course of creating a new node.

Take out the pre-defined text and things will start to work as desired for your function $.jstree.defaults.unique.duplicate !

```
self.createFileNode = function (data) {
  //Below code only allows files to be created within folders.
  //Structure it as per createFolder method to create files at root
   var data = {
          //'id': 'tempId',
          //'text': 'iOS 8'
     }
....
```

In that case of course a new node's text will be the default 'New node'.

The best is to set a unique node name right upfront on creating a new node, like `"text" : "OS_" + (new Date).getTime()`.

Still for the case of renaming nodes and duplicates: using the unique plugin, on renaming and choosing a duplicate text the node's text will fall back to the original one. If that is not what is desired, things get more complicated as the rename_node.jstree event will not be fired in that case.